# How To Hide The page Names and directories In URL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, url

I am Developing a site in ASP .NET.. so by running or accessing my site the URL comes by revealing on what directory and name of the page

I've seen some sites by hiding such contents like

(www.website.com/# )

so nothing can be seen

how to implement it in my site???

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this?  It does not make your site any more secure against malicious users, and it's incredibly annoying if users can't bookmark or link to specific pages on your site.

Comment: Note that it's usually the goal of a developer to do the opposite of this... Make the urls _more_ informative. It helps with bookmarks, search engine optmisation and other things.

Answer (score 1):

Websites with urls ending with /# are Single Page Applications. All application code is retrieved by a single page load. Actually, the hash mark ensures that no request is made to the server after the initial. This allows all routing to happen client side. Data is often fetched from web services by making ajax calls.

But implementing this for an existing site can be a very big task. What you are after is simply just routing. you can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

It allows you to tell your webserver, that if a request comes to /cuteanimals, it should look for the page in /pictures/animals/cute/index.aspx